# What does "-" (dash) means in bash?

Tags: bash, s3cmd

I ran the following command that I found on internet.

```
s3cmd ls --recursive  s3://bucket/files  | awk '{print $4}' |  xargs -I@ s3cmd get @ -
```

a) Can anyone break this down from the xargs part
b) I specifically want to know what does "-" means in bash.

Sorry if the title is misleading.

Comment: It *doesn't* mean anything in or to bash itself. That said, it's likely that `s3cmd` takes it to mean "stdin or stdout, as appropriate", as this is the conventional meaning. See Guideline 13 at the end of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html

Comment: ...so, in that case, we're telling `s3cmd` to run a `get` with the `@` replaced with result from the `s3cmd ls ... | awk` command line, and a `-` meaning that that result should be written to stdout.

Comment: Got you. Thank you so much for clearing this.